# SQL Design, Duplicate data for speed?

Tags: database-design, relational-database

When I want to track user logins, I have separate table for logins.
Ie.

```
uid, login_time
```

and table for users

```
id, username, password
```

After millions of logins, is it good to have separate column for login time in user table or is it useless. And what is bestway to query users and their last login.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the ability to both audit all logins and query a users last login then IMHO writing to a last_login_time column on the user table at the same time as writing your login audit record would suffice. Then a query for most recent login is going to be more efficient than trawling through the audit table